# Subprocess.call() not running on my django view , Why the view code runs perfectly in the manage.py shell

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I am trying to do video cropping using `ffmpeg` on the server, once the video file uploaded by the user is saved, then I run `ffmpeg` command on it to crop the video and further replace the uploaded file with cropped file using `mv` command. Though this code works perfectly when run step by step in `manage.py` console, the uploaded file is not getting cropped while testing.

```
new_video.save()
url=new_video.video_file.url
real_path = "/home/chanceapp/webapps/chanceapp/chanceapp"+url
fake_crop_path = "/home/chanceapp/webapps/chanceapp/chanceapp/fake1"+url
rotate_crop = "ffmpeg -i %s -vf "%(real_path)+r'"transpose=2 , crop=480:480:0:0" '+\
    "-vcodec libx264 -strict -2 -crf 18 %s"%(fake_crop_path)
move_cropped = "mv"+" %s"%(fake_crop_path)+" %s"%(real_path)
commands = [rotate_crop,move_cropped]
for command in commands:
    subprocess.call(command,shell=True )
```

Thankyou.

Comment: That's not your question, but please realize that his code is highly vulnerable to shell injection. You should *never*  use `shell=True` with unsanitized input that is coming from the internet.

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You should debug it more:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

for command in commands:
    result = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
    if len(result) > 0:
        raise Exception(result)
```

Does it raise any exception?